# jq: Remove items from array that match a condition based on other items in the same array

Tags: json, jq

I need help with a somewhat complex jq query.

Given

```
[{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1710829,
  "participantId": 2,
  "itemId": 3089
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1711620,
  "participantId": 7,
  "itemId": 2055
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1711621,
  "participantId": 7,
  "itemId": 1058
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1714435,
  "participantId": 9,
  "itemId": 1037
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_UNDO",
  "timestamp": 1716107,
  "participantId": 7,
  "afterId": 0,
  "beforeId": 2055
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_UNDO",
  "timestamp": 1716272,
  "participantId": 7,
  "afterId": 0,
  "beforeId": 1058
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1718091,
  "participantId": 7,
  "itemId": 1026
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1710829,
  "participantId": 2,
  "itemId": 3089
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1714435,
  "participantId": 9,
  "itemId": 1037
},
{
  "type": "ITEM_PURCHASED",
  "timestamp": 1718091,
  "participantId": 7,
  "itemId": 1026
}]
```

I would like to filter this array and remove all the purchased items that were "undone".
A PURCHASE_ITEM object can be undone by adding an ITEM_UNDONE object after it with a higher timestamp, a matching participantId and beforeId==itemId.

I tried the following approach:

1. Collect all the ITEM_UNDO objects
2. Find all corresponding ITEM_PURCHASED objects
3. Subtract both from the original list

Step 2 is giving me trouble.
I have the following code so far which does not work:

```
jq '
map(select(.type=="ITEM_UNDO")) as $undos |
 [
    {
      undo: $undos[],
      before_purchases: map( select(.type=="ITEM_PURCHASED"
                                    and .itemId == $undos[].beforeId
                                    and .participantId == $undos[].participantId
                                    )

                           )
    }
  ] as $undo_with_purchased | $undo_with_purchased
'
```

I know why it doesn't work because in the line

```
and .itemId == $undos[].beforeId
and .participantId == $undos[].participantId
```

$undos is expanded twice independently rather than using the same instance for every comparison and then a third time in

```
undo: $undos[],
```

I can't seem to find a good way to force jq to iterate over $undos only once and use the same instance for all comparisons. In general I'm having issues iterating over multiple arrays at the same time, performing operations. This would be a no brainer in any procedural language but what's the best way to do this kind of stuff in jq?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's define a filter that will tell if an item in the array has been "undone" by a subsequent (in the array and in time) item.  This is straightforward to do using `any/2`:

```
# input: the entire array
# output: true iff item n is "undone" by a subsequent item
def undone($n):
  . as $in
  | length as $length
  | .[$n] as $nth
  | if $nth.type != "ITEM_PURCHASED" then false
    else any( range($n+1; $length) | $in[.]; 
              .type == "ITEM_UNDO"
              and .participantId == $nth.participantId
              and .beforeId== $nth.itemId
              and .timestamp > $nth.timestamp)
    end;
```

Now the query is quite straightforward:

```
[ range(0;length) as $i
  | select( (.[$i].type == "ITEM_PURCHASED") and (undone($i) | not) )
  | .[$i] ]
```

Invocation: jq -f program.jq data.json

Output: an array with the three items.

#### Style

One can write:

```
range($n+1; $length) | $in[.]
```

more compactly, and perhaps more idiomatically, as:

```
$in[range($n+1; $length)]
```

In fact, both `$in` and `$length` can be dispensed with altogether, so the snippet in question would become simply:

```
.[range($n+1; length)]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I was considering taking this approach of testing _every_ ITEM_PURCHASED whether it had been undone later. But then I thought that would be inefficient if there are lots of ITEM_PURCHASED but only few ITEM_UNDONE. It seems that collecting the ITEM_UNDO objects upfront should be more efficient. What are your thoughts? (I'm not expecting code, just want your opinion)

Comment: The original problem description stated that "A PURCHASE_ITEM object can be undone by adding an ITEM_UNDONE object **after it**  ...".  If that is actually a requirement, then the ordering is important (and actually helpful).  If that is NOT a requirement but merely an optimization hint, then I'd want to know more about the actual requirements, including what if anything can be assumed about the data.  Another thing to remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming.